# Java writer first character (int) in output wrong

Tags: java, int, character, writer

I am trying to write an writer in Java which takes integer values out of an `ArrayList` for the first row and column and a `float[][]` for the rest and formats it into a CSV. Doing this my first column gets weird and I can't find the problem. I would be really happy for any suggestions or help. Here is my code:

```
public static void resulttofile(List<Nm_item> nmvector,
        float[][] cor_matrix, String filename) {
    try {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File(filename + ".csv"));
        for (int i = nmvector.get(0).row; i <= nmvector
                .get(nmvector.size() - 1).row; i++) {
            writer.write(sepw + nmvector.get(i).nm);
        }
        writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        for (int i = nmvector.get(0).row; i <= nmvector
                .get(nmvector.size() - 1).row; i++) {
            writer.write(nmvector.get(i).nm);

            for (int j = nmvector.get(0).row; j <= nmvector.get(nmvector
                    .size() - 1).row; j++) {
                writer.write(sepw + cor_matrix[i][j]);
            }
            writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }

        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Results saved to " + filename + ".csv");
}
```

and the output (cropped):

```
        350 351 352 353
?   0   0.003   0.171   0.001
?   0.003   0   0.274   0
è   0.163   0.271   0   0.345
Ü   0   0   0.35    0
?   0.008   0.019   0.326   0.044
?   0.008   0.016   0.199   0.015
?   0.015   0.037   0.361   0.04
?   0.029   0.023   0.171   0.023
?   0.038   0.042   0.186   0.038
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
writer.write(Integer.toString(nmvector.get(i).nm));
```

Or, as OldCurmudgeon says:

```
writer.write("" + nmvector.get(i).nm);
```

The point is that [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) contains more than one `write` method. There is [write(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write%28int%29) and [write(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write%28java.lang.String%29). The first one doesn't write the number, it writes the character that corresponds to the number given, so for example `writer.write(88)` will output the character 'X', `writer.write(89)` will output 'Y', and you can guess what `writer.write(90)` will give you. You need to convert the integer to a String so that the right `write()` method is called.

The second form `writer.write("" + number)` works because when you add a number to a String the Java compiler will automatically convert the number into a String for you. This is why `writer.write(sepw + nmvector.get(i).nm);` works but `writer.write(nmvector.get(i).nm);` doesn't.

Comment: Or `writer.write(""+nmvector.get(i).nm);`

Comment: Both works, thank you. Is this because you can not open a line with an int but always an String?

Comment: Hi Helge, I've added a bit more explanation to my answer. Hope that helps.